# How to rename and delete a file in a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Locally when docker copies file, I have a folder that has 2 files:

database.yml
database.docker.yml

When I run `docker-compose up` I want to delete the file `database.yml` and then rename the other file `database.docker.yml` to `database.yml`

This is what I have now but it isn't working:

```
ADD . /app
RUN rm /app/config/database.yml
RUN mv /app/config/database.docker.yml /app/config/database.yml
```

My docker-compose for this service is:

```
rails:
    build: ../rails-web
    volumes:
     - ../rails-web:/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: puma -C config/puma.rb
    env_file:
      - '.env'
```

Comment: how do you know it's not working? Have you looked inside the container?

Comment: @AlexKarshin yes when I look inside the container, the content of database.yml is not database.docker.yml

Comment: Can you post `docker-compose.yml`?

Comment: @AlexKarshin I posted it, but not sure if it is relevant.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that during build you add `/app`, remove the old config and move the new config. But then `docker-compose up` starts the container and you *overwrite* the `/app` folder with your local one - by mapping it with your `volumes` directive.

Fix? `EITHER` remove `volumes` from `docker-compose.yml` -- but in this case you will have to rebuild the image every time you introduce changes to your code. `OR` rewrite `volumes` like this:

```
rails:
    ...
    volumes:
     - ../rails-web:/app
     - ../rails-web/config/database.docker.yml:/app/config/database.yml
    ...
```

It will map the docker config to your "old" config.